# How to split multiple sentences in part by part in Dart, flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, split, flutter-test

I want to split a paragraph with multiple sentences part by part. Specifically, I want to show 1st sentence in a Text widget and then remaining of the sentence in another Text widget. How can I achieve this?

var str = 'Taste the crunchy and spicy goodness of our potato chips! Our chips are sure to tantalize your taste buds, leaving you wanting more! And with their irresistible flavor, you won't be able to resist the temptation to indulge. So why not grab a bag today and experience the deliciousness of our potato chips? You won't regret';

```
var parts = str.split(' ');

var prefix = parts[0].trim();
var prefix1 = parts[1].trim();

print(prefix); // Taste
print(prefix1); // the
```

It prints out word by word but not sentence by sentence..

Comment: If sentence is separated by period (.) then you should split it using str.split('.') instead of space. Let me know if I am getting you right.

Comment: you're right. But I want to split multiple sentences into 2 parts. 1st part will be 1st sentence only and the 2nd part will be the remaining sentences. If I use (.) it will split sentences whenever it finds a period(.)

Answer (score 0):

If your sentences are separated by `periods (.)`, you can do something like this:

```
String str = "first. second. third.";
// get the position of the first period
int index = str.indexOf(".");
// get first sentence
var firstPart = str.substring(0, index + 1).trim();
// get the rest of sentences
var secondPart = str.substring(index + 1).trim();
```

update:
if you sentences can end with `(. or ! or ?)`, you can use a `RegEx` as an argument to indexOf method

```
int index = str.indexOf(RegExp(r'[\.\?\!]'));
```

Comment: sentences are separated by (. ! ?). That's why it wasn't giving the output I would expect with this solution. I tried few different methods in the mean time and seems like one solution is working how I expected. Solution: var str = 'apple. ball! cat?'; List<String> parts = str.split(RegExp(r'(?<=[.!?])\s')); var prefix = parts[0]; var prefix1 = parts.sublist(1).join(' ');

Comment: you can use indexOf like this:
str.indexOf(RegExp(r'[\.\?\!]'))

Comment: Thank you for the update. The solution I stated above seems like working fine at this moment.

Comment: your solution works but I think it's less efficient as you're splitting and joining again where you don't need to do this in the indexOf based solution

Comment: good point. I will also try out your solution. thank you.